# Dynamically resize the pixi stage and it's contents on window resize and window load

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, pixi.js

I'm trying to dynamically resize the pixi stage (canvas and contents) on window resize.  And also have it initially load at the size of the browser window without changing ratio.

I'm using the following to set the initial size basically to `window.innerWidth` & `window.innerHeight`.

But it's doing something strange, it's loading at a smaller size (but not the size of the canvas specified in the html) then it's expanding to fit the window.

```
var w;
var h;
    
window.onload = function() {
    var w = window.innerWidth;
    var h = window.innerHeight;

    //this part resizes the canvas but keeps ratio the same
    renderer.view.style.width = w + "px";
    renderer.view.style.height = h + "px"

//  init();
};
```

Here's my onresize function - it's resizing the canvas, but not the content.

I thought being that it's updating the `renderer.view`, it would resize the content, but it's not doing so.

How do I resize the content of the `stage/renderer.view` content?

```
window.onresize = function (event){
    var w = window.innerWidth;
    var h = window.innerHeight;

    //this part resizes the canvas but keeps ratio the same
    renderer.view.style.width = w + "px";
    renderer.view.style.height = h + "px";

    //this part adjusts the ratio:
    renderer.resize(w,h);
}

    // create an new instance of a pixi stage
    var stage = new PIXI.Stage(0xff00ff);
    var renderer = PIXI.autoDetectRenderer(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

    // add the renderer view element to the DOM
   var mypixiStage = document.body.appendChild(renderer.view);
```

Comment: What ratio do you want to keep? Or, what's the default canvas size?

Comment: That's a really good question :D  Right now it's 1920x1080, so 16x9. But that might need to change later. I  edited the above fyi.

Comment: Did my answer help at all?

Comment: Late to the party, but I encountered the same issue of it not resizing and resolved it simply by using `window.addEventListener("resize", onResizeHandler)` instead of `window.onresize = onResizeHandler`.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You will want to setup a size and ratio for the resize event function to reference. Then, you'll need a resize function that checks the window size in order to keep the ratio when resized. I'm also running the resize function manually to start for initial page load.

Also, note that I'm not running `renderer.resize`. I'm just resizing the drawing area.

Here's a fiddle for you to look at: http://jsfiddle.net/2wjw043f/

Here's the fiddle code:

```
var size = [1920, 1080];
var ratio = size[0] / size[1];
var stage = new PIXI.Stage(0x333333, true);
var renderer = PIXI.autoDetectRenderer(size[0], size[1], null);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.view);
var texture = new PIXI.RenderTexture();
r1 = new PIXI.Graphics();
r1.beginFill(0x00ffff);
r1.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
r1.endFill();
texture.render(r1);
var block = new PIXI.Sprite(texture);
block.position.x = 100;
block.position.y = 100;
block.anchor.x = .5;
block.anchor.y = .5;
stage.addChild(block);
requestAnimFrame(animate);
resize();
function animate() {
    requestAnimFrame(animate);
    block.rotation += .01;
    renderer.render(stage);
}
function resize() {
    if (window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight >= ratio) {
        var w = window.innerHeight * ratio;
        var h = window.innerHeight;
    } else {
        var w = window.innerWidth;
        var h = window.innerWidth / ratio;
    }
    renderer.view.style.width = w + 'px';
    renderer.view.style.height = h + 'px';
}
window.onresize = resize;
```

Comment: I bookmarked your JSFiddle few days ago and now it does not work anymore. Console says something about PIXI not being defined. Would you please fix it? Edit: Nevermind, looks like the domain that hosted external pixi (goodboydigital) is down.

Answer (score 54):

Starting from PixiJS 5.0 you can simply use the [**resizeTo**](https://pixijs.download/release/docs/PIXI.Application.html#resizeTo) property of your Application:

```
let app = new PIXI.Application({ resizeTo: window });
```

Documentation: http://pixijs.download/release/docs/PIXI.Application.html#Application

Comment: This works, but does not redraw element positions - just the canvas size. I created a feature request for that: https://github.com/pixijs/pixi.js/issues/6081

Comment: Notice if you're using Pixi on websites: This creates a performance issue in mobile browsers during scroll. Resizes every time the window resizes, which is quite often given the browser hides/shows the url bar. It may cause flickering etc.

Answer (score 4):

I been using Pixi.js for a few weeks and worked on the same problem of resizing the canvas. This class creates a sprite that has a method "applyResize" that does most of the work. The size of the canvas background will equal the same as the parent "domElement" in the constructor. You have to add 'resize' event listener to the sprite after initializing it. Or you can do something else to improve it.

```js
class PixiBackground {

    constructor(type = 'cover', domElement, imgUrl) {
        this.domElement = domElement;
        this.imgUrl = imgUrl;
        this.parent = new PIXI.Container();
        this.sprite = new PIXI.Sprite.fromImage(this.imgUrl);
        this.parent.addChild(this.sprite);
        this.type = type;
    }

    addTo(container) {
        container.addChild(this.parent);
        this.applyResize();
    }

    applyResize() {
        const domSize = {
            x: this.domElement.clientWidth,
            y: this.domElement.clientHeight
        };
        const imageSize = {
            x: this.sprite.texture.width,
            y: this.sprite.texture.height
        };
        const domElementRatio = domSize.x / domSize.y;
        const imageRatio = imageSize.x / imageSize.y;
        var scale = 1;
        var position = new PIXI.Point(0, 0);

        if (this.type == 'cover' ? domElementRatio > imageRatio : domElementRatio < imageRatio) {
            //photo is taller than background
            scale = domSize.x / imageSize.x;
            position.y = -(imageSize.y * scale - domSize.y) / 2;
            position.x = 0;
        } else {
            //photo is wider than background
            scale = domSize.y / imageSize.y;
            position.x = -(imageSize.x * scale - domSize.x) / 2;
            position.y = 0;
        }
        this.sprite.scale = new PIXI.Point(scale, scale);
        this.sprite.position = position;
        return this;
    }
}

const imgUrl = 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1528723624453-3e53a413b392?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=85&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=srgb&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ&s=b44ae61a30e1a05f5defbf48cb5956eb';
const canvasParentElement = document.getElementById('canvasParentElement');
const renderer = PIXI.autoDetectRenderer({
    width: canvasParentElement.clientWidth,
    height: canvasParentElement.clientHeight
});
canvasParentElement.appendChild(renderer.view);

const stage = new PIXI.Container();
const pixiTestObject = new PixiBackground('cover', canvasParentElement, imgUrl);

PIXI.loader.add(imgUrl).load(function() {
    pixiTestObject.addTo(stage)
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);

    function animate() {
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        renderer.render(stage);
    }
});

window.addEventListener('resize', debounce(() => onResizeWindow(), 250));
window.addEventListener('resize', debounce(() => pixiTestObject.applyResize(), 250));

// From underscrore.js
function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
    let timeout;
    return function() {
        let args = arguments;
        let later = () => {
            timeout = null;
            if (!immediate) func.apply(this, args);
        };
        let callNow = immediate && !timeout;
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
        if (callNow) func.apply(this, args);
    }
}

function onResizeWindow() {
    const canvas = renderer.view;
    const w = canvasParentElement.clientWidth;
    const h = canvasParentElement.clientHeight;
    canvas.style.width = w + 'px';
    canvas.style.height = h + 'px';
    canvas.width = w;
    canvas.height = h;
    renderer.resize(w, h);
}
```

```css
  #canvasParentElement {
    background: black;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pixi.js/4.8.1/pixi.min.js"></script>
<div id="canvasParentElement"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

For my use case, I only need to scale a sprite based on its width. I do this using the `scale` function and clamping it to a max value of 1:

```js
sprite.scale.set(Math.min(app.screen.width / sprite.texture.width, 1))
```

Starting with PixiJS 5.3.0 there's an `resize` event emitted on the renderer. This is thanks to [issue #6081](https://github.com/pixijs/pixi.js/issues/6081) opened by Fabian von Ellerts that he mentioned in his comment.

```js
app.renderer.on('resize', (width, height) => {
  sprite.scale.set(Math.min(width / sprite.texture.width, 1))
})
```

⚠️ This will only set the dimensions of the sprite. You'll still need to position it on the canvas in a similar manner, i.e also scale its position.

Answer (score 0):

```
app.renderer.resize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
window.onresize = function()
{
    app.renderer.resize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var mobiledev;
if (window.innerWidth <= window.innerHeight){
   mobiledev = true;
   app.renderer.resize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight + (((((window.innerWidth * 100) / window.innerHeight) / 100) - 0.5) * window.innerWidth));
    } else {
   mobiledev = false;
   app.renderer.resize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight - (((((window.innerHeight * 100) / window.innerWidth) / 100) - 0.65) * window.innerWidth));
    }
```

I have been using PIXI.js for like close to a year and encountered problem when it came to resizing and responsiveness. This is a block of code I came up with and haven't had issues with responsiveness. I created an if statement to check for the device resolution and place the items according to it

Answer (score 0):

A CSS solution would be more viable and better choice for resizing the canvas rather than updating it from window `"resize"` events that the others have answered, since you do not need to change the contents' positions and could give better performance.

You can add a canvas element with an `id` of your choice in your HTML file and assign it to the `view` property of your application.

```html
<canvas id="game"></canvas>
```

```js
const app = new PIXI.Application({
    width: 960,
    height: 540,

    view: document.getElementById("game")
});
```

Then, add this into your CSS file:

```css
#game {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;

    width: 100vw; 
    max-width: 100%; /* ensures that it doesn't overflow */
    height: auto;
    max-height: 100%; /* ensures that it doesn't overflow */

    user-select: none; /* removes accidental selection */
}
```

Adjust the CSS properties to however it fits your website.